# Exchange: Auto Reply Rules

Tags: exchange, powershell

Is there a way to disable or remove the Automatic Reply Rules that can be created in Outlook with Powershell? They can be reached by clicking the 'Rules...' button under the 'Automatic Replies' window within Outlook.

We have employees that use these rules to forward emails to their personal emails, but they sometimes forget to turn them off when they leave the organization. I can disable inbox rules using the 'Remove-InboxRule' cmdlet, but I cannot find anything for these type of rules.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638217%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) is probably what you're after:

```
Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity "Mr. Leaver" -AutoReplyState Disabled
```

In an automation scenario, use the `-Confirm:$false` switch to circumvent manual confirmation

Comment: Mathias - Thank you for the reply. If the Out-Of-Office is turned off, it is not a problem. Although, we like to leave this on for a month with a message to contact someone else in the organization for further information. M M

Answer (score 0):

I just did this.  The Automatic Reply Rules are not the same as "Inbox Rules", however, you can see them using Get-InboxRule using the -IncludeHidden switch.

You can then use the Remove-InboxRule command to get ride of it, using the mailbox id and RuleIdentity values.